# Collection vs Model confusion in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I just started learning backbone.js. I have a problem understanding how/when use models and collections. I found several tutorial online and each of them use different approach of building the application. There are cases where data is retrieved from REST API in a Collection object, in other examples in a Model object? I also noticed in every example json data was in format like 
`{'id':1, 'name':'some name'}`. 
My api returns a bit more complex data structure - something like `{'message':'response message', 'error':'', 'data': [{list of data objects to be manipulated},{}]}`. Is it possible to use such formatted data in backbone.js.

Answer (score 20):

Well, yes, for both of your questions. Typically here is how the Relational database system relates to backbone.js:

- Your **model** is a record from a table of the database.
- Your **collections** are the table itself. So set of models make up the collection.
- **Views** are used to define **how your model should look** and **what it should do**. There are views for your models, collections and intermediate data.

Your response if different; hence, you need to parse the data before it is set to the model, collection. Use the [parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) method and define the data key.

Comment: Thanks that was very informative. In my case one of the calls to the API returns a set of records that I need to display. If I'm understanding correctly I should make that api call in the Collection object?

Comment: @marcin_koss correct :). Set the url and call `collectionInstance.fetch()` it will automatically get the data for you. The Collection view should subscribe to `reset` event and you should re-render during that event to keep the view in sync with data . have a happy day